# global set up in django test framework?

Tags: python, django, testing

Is there some way (using the standard Django.test.TestCase framework) to perform a global initialization of certain variables, so that it only happens *once*.

Putting things setUp() makes it so that the variables are initialized before each test, which kills performance when the setup involves expensive operations. I'd like to run a setup type feature once, and then have the variables initialized here be visible to all my tests.

I'd prefer not to rewrite the test runner framework.

I am thinking of something similar to a before(:all) in the Ruby/RSpec world.

-S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to "re-write the whole test runner framework" but you will need to create a custom test_runner (you can just [copy the existing one](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/test/simple.py) and modify it to include your global setup code). It's about 100 lines of code. Then set the [TEST_RUNNER](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#setting-TEST_RUNNER) setting to point to your custom runner and away you go.

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#using-different-testing-frameworks

Comment: Right - I was trying to avoid a custom test runner - doesn't look like I may have a choice. 

The more I work with Django, the more I miss Rails. Python has much better scientific library support though, so I guess I can live with it.

Comment: I think the test runner used to be like 15-30 lines of code in older Django versions so they probably didn't consider it a big deal to copy it and create a new one. It got changed into a whole Class and grew in size in later versions. You could always suggest a feature request to add in a way to run some additional setup code (maybe in setup_test_environment()) without specifying a whole new runner (an additional setting or global signal)?

Comment: Thanks again for the tips - I was looking for a nice declarative way to do this along the lines of setUp() but it looks like I may have to rig up a runner. A feature request make sense.

Comment: @shreddd, hi, is your new feature request accepted by django? I also want a feature like this.

Comment: @linebreak - Sorry, the original question/answer was from 2010 and that's probably the last time I really used Django. :( Maybe start a new question for v1.8?

Comment: I am sorted, default test runner is fine, this was my fault, just need to keep the tests focused and isolated.

Answer (score 3):

This is partially addressed in newer versions of python/django by setUpClass() which will at least allow me to run class level setup.

Answer (score 0):

What about a class with static variables ?
Something like :

```
class InitialSetup(object):
    GEOLOCATOR = GeoLocator()
    DEFAULT_LOCATION = GEOLOCATOR.get_geocode_object(settings.DEFAULT_ADDRESS, with_country=True)

    def setUp(self):
        self.geolocator = InitialSetup.GEOLOCATOR
        self.default_location = InitialSetup.DEFAULT_LOCATION
        p = Page.objects.create(site_id=settings.SITE_ID, template='home_page.html')
        p.publish()
        self.client = Client()


class AccessTest(InitialSetup, Testcase):  # Diamond inheritance issue! inheritance order matters
    def setUp(self):
        super(AccessTest, self).setUp()


    def test_access(self):
        # Issue a GET request.
        response = self.client.get('/')

        # Check that the response is 200 OK.
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: Hi Maazza - yes one can hack around the problem by setting up static or class variables. However, I was looking for a declarative built-in solution. Looks like this is partially solved in newer versions of python with the setUpClass() function.